# even continuous function that is convex and vanishes at infinity and has value $1$ at $0$ is a characterisitc function

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I would like to get some feedback on the answer I wrote below:

The problem is from a textbook I'm reading: problem 3.2.8 of [Probability Theory Lecture Notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6JeBUquZ5BwVlV1dEpsTHVVbTA/view?resourcekey=0-5xbvKhDXZjrYRLfqppsHuQ) by Panchenko. I posted about 3.2.7 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319822) which is in relation to 3.2.8. Here's the question:

> 3.2.8. Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 1$, $f(t) = f(-t)$  for all $t$, and such that $f$ restricted to $[0,\infty)$ is convex, with $f(t)\to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. Show that $f$ is a characteristic function. (Hint: Approximate the general case by piecewise linear. Then use that $\max(1-|t|,0)$ is a characteristic function and that characteristic functions are closed under convex combinations and scaling $f(t)\to 
> f(at)$ for $a\in\mathbb R$.)

Answer: I looked this up and found an answer in Feller's intro to probability and its applications pages 505 and 509 ([link to pdf](http://www.ru.ac.bd/stat/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2019/03/101_06_Feller_An-Introduction-to-Probability-Theory-and-Its-Applications-Vol.-2.pdf)). Here it goes:
As it is given in the hint, the idea is to approximate $f$ with piecewise linear functions.

- Piecewise linear functions can be written as a convex combination of rescalings of $\phi(t):= \max(1-|t|,0)$. Proof: Think of a piecewise linear function that is convex and is even as a convex polygon that is symmetric w.r.t. to the $y$-axis. Then, we can write
  $$f(t)= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i\phi(t/a_i)$$
  where $\sum_i^np_i=1$ so that $f(0)=1$, and $a_i>0$, and $n$ is the number of sides on the positive side. This is clearly a convex combination of rescalings of $\phi(t)$.
- By 3.2.7 (linked post), we know that $\max(1-|t|,0)$ is a characteristic function.
- Therefore, since rescalings of characteristic functions are characteristic functions, and since convex combination of them is also a characteristic function, any piecewise linear function is a characteristic function.
- Now, let $f_n$ be a piecewise linear function that approximates $f$. By Levy's continuity theorem (theorem 3.5 of the same book), since $f_n\to f$ pointwise and each $f_n$ is a characteristic function, $f$ is also a characteristic function.

Comment: you still haven't justified why such $f_n$ exist. but if you do, then this looks right

Comment: @peek-a-boo does the answer to this post finish the proof?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562650/piecewise-linear-continuous-approximation-of-continuous-function

Comment: one technical detail is that in those arguments, the piecewise-linear functions are obtained by interpolating $f$ between infinitely many points; i.e each $f_n$ is a series of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\text{(linear stuff)}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\text{some interval}}$. So, when you try to write this as a convex combination of rescalings of $\phi$, there are going to be infinitely many terms. So, you have to generalize your first bullet point to show that even infinite convex combinations $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i\phi(t/a_i)$ are still characteristic functions